# Cant install DBI.pm & DBD.pm for RHEL to run perl scripts

Tags: perl, installation, rhel

I am trying to execute a perl script that interacts with mysql database. I am on `RHEL 5.5` and my **mysql version is 5.0.77**. And it returned error that it requires `DBI.pm` module for perl. I tried to install it via `cpan`, using `perl -MCPAN -e "install DBI.pm"`. It tries to some ftp server which times out.

I tried manually install from repo of cpan. DBI.pm installed properly and I proceeded with DBD.pm but cpan repo has DBD.pm only for mysql 4.

I am lost... any pointers?

Comment: try download and install Manually(i.e. by using make)or you can also do `cpan>install specific/DBD-mysql-version.tar.gz`

Comment: Could you install mysql and DBI from Redhat packages instead of from source?  And [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql) will work with mysql 5 despite the version number being 4.x.

Comment: I cant cpan because its looking up for some obsolete ftp path which is not up anymore. Redhat 64 bit Packages do not have dbd... :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

RHEl 5.5 64 bit has Perl 5.08 which does not support DBD and DBI, one needs to upgrade the Perl to atleast 5.10 to get things working. Yet to figure out how to do the upgrade.

Comment: RHEL 5.5 includes perl 5.8.8. DBI's current minimum perl version is 5.8.1.

Answer (score 5):

You're on RHEL, so why not install via yum?

```
yum install perl-DBD-mysql
```

In general, if you want to install a perl package via yum, you can do

```
yum install 'perl(Module::Name)'
```

Comment: I have the same problem and `yum install 'perl(DBI::DBD)'` solved my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

it works for me!

perl -MCPAN -e "install DBI"